# WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS is not recognized

Tags: android

I am trying to run the following through adb for granting WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS to my Marshmallow Rom.

My phone is already rooted.

However I am getting this exception :

```
1|root@:/ # pm grant by4a.setedit22 Android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SE
TINGS
.setedit22 Android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS                  <
Bad argument: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown permission: Android.M
nifest.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
usage: pm list packages [-f] [-d] [-e] [-s] [-3] [-i] [-u] [--user USER_ID] [FI
TER]
       pm list permission-groups
       pm list permissions [-g] [-f] [-d] [-u] [GROUP]
       pm list instrumentation [-f] [TARGET-PACKAGE]
```

Can anyone please help me out here ?

Comment: huh! I just found this old non answered question...just use android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS (without Manifest word)